# Three finger robotic arm history

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, microcontroller

I have a picture with robotic arm which comes from lego video ([Lego Mindstorms Robotics Invention System 2.0 tour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rex8SYJRvT0)) and I was wondering when and where it was created.

Very interesting stuff. It was probably most advanced three finger hand those days.
I'll be very grateful for answer. Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: please add a link to the source of the picture ... add it to the question ... **do not** write a comment

Comment: what is the date stamp on the picture file?

Comment: The picture comes from video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rex8SYJRvT0

Comment: the video is from around 2004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `Salisbury Hand / Stanford/JPL Hand`

Built sometime in 1983, as per the following link.

https://www.robotgrasping.org/#Salisbury%20Hand%20/%20Stanford/JPL%20Hand

[image]

picture from https://americanhistory.si.edu/sites/default/files/file-uploader/Salisbury%20Hand%20Rectangle.jpg